# A class of Grothendieck categories

Tags: abelian-categories

Is there a name and some work on Grothendieck categories in which each non-zero object has a simple subquotient? Every locally finitely generated Grothendieck category has this property, but I guess that many other ones possess it. Many thanks in advance if you have examples, references, properties about it!